# Is there way to define clickable are of a marker in v2 map api

Tags: android, android-maps-v2

I have a custom marker png. I want to define part of it as clickable are so if the user clicks/touch other areas marker click event wouldn't trigger. Is this possible in map v2? If so how to implement it?

This is my custom marker.I want only the white box that has a plus sign to be clickable.

[image]

Comment: you should use the InfoWindow and manage those click.
In Android API when you click on a marker you just get the "MarkerClick" callback with which marker has clicked, but not which point on the screen.

Comment: Can't use infowindows. this should always show